# python list from both strings and for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Is there a way to create a list using both strings and a generator (for loop).

list() only takes one argument. The only way I can see so far is:

```
row = ['string1','string2']+list((t.string3[-7:]) for t in tobject)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Well I mean... what are you hoping it might look like? What are you hoping to gain compared to what you have now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to do it in only one line? `chain()` works, but it looks so unreadable to me. The following is probably less elegant, but I think it's far more readable:

```
row = ['string1', 'string2']
row.extend(t.string3[-7:] for t in tobject)
```

Comment: Actually, in this _particular_ case, I find this more elegant than `chain`.

Comment: What makes this less elegant?  Sometimes 2 lines are better than 1. (+1 from me)

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain(('string1','string2'), (t.string3[-7:] for t in tobject)))
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to concatenate two lists.

You may prefer to [`chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) the iterables and then call `list` on them once.